# The rank nullity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I was studying the Rank Nullity theoreom and found this explanation that I think I'll be happy with if I really understood it, as it's easy to remember. They're supposing that the equation is on the form Ax = b, where A is our matrix.

[image]

How come that if we have more freedom in choosing our x, this gives us less freedom in choosing our b and vice versa?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds quite badly taken out of context (to the extent that we have to guess what they mean by $x$ and $b$).

Comment: Dimensions can be thought of in terms of degrees of freedom (think about 1,2 and 3 dimensions for instance). So, if dim(R)+dim(N) is kept constant, the more one increases, the more the other decreases. Could I make myself clear?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I edited my post. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @SayanDutta Yes, I understand that part. But how can this relate to the equation Ax = b?

Comment: @Tanamas check [this](http://mitran-lab.amath.unc.edu/courses/MATH547/lessons/Lesson10.pdf)

Comment: The more values of $x$ there are that work for a given $b$, the fewer values of $x$ there are left to work for other values of $b$, so the fewer values of $b$ there are for which there's a value of $x$ that works. So, the more freedom we have in choosing $x$, the less freedom we have in choosing $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will expand on Gerry Myerson's comment.$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$

---

**Setup.** $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, and $b$ is a $m \times 1$ column vector. We are wishing to solve $$Ax = b \tag{$*$}$$ for $n \times 1$ column vectors $x$.

$\N(A)$ denotes the *null space* of $A$. That is, it is the set of all those column vectors $x$ such that $Ax = 0$. In other words, the solution set to $(*)$ upon putting $b = 0$.

$\im(A)$ denotes the *image* of $A$. That is, it is the set of all those column vectors $b$ such that $(*)$ has at least one solution.

---

The key point is the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Suppose $x_0$ is a particular solution of $(*)$. Then, the set of all solutions of $(*)$ is precisely equal to $x_0 + \N(A)$.

Thus, $\N(A)$ measures exactly "how many" solutions there are to $(*)$, **assuming that there is at least one solution**.

---

Now, the rank-nullity theorem tells you that $$\dim(\N(A)) + \dim(\im(A)) = n \tag{$\dagger$}.$$
For the purpose of this question, assume that $A$ is varying over all $m \times n$ matrices. Thus, the right hand side of $(\dagger)$ is constant.

This means that if $\N(A)$ is "larger", then $\im(A)$ is "smaller". But note that $\N(A)$ measures how many $x$ there are which solve $(*)$ <sub>(assuming there is at least one solution)</sub>, whereas $\im(A)$ measures how many $b$ there are for which $(*)$ can be solved.

Comment: Ohhh! That made alot of sense. Thank you really! I think there's still some doubt though, I don't really know why. I understand the algebraic part, but I think it'd become alot easier if I had a geometrical intuition behind all of it, maybe i'll remember it more easily then. Maybe you got one? Thank you anyways though, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Tanamas: Glad it helped. I don't think I have a better geometric intuition than quite literally translating the above thing. For example, let us consider that $n = 3$ and $m = 4$. Then, you have four options for the dimension of image of $A$: $0, 1, 2, 3$. Correspondingly, the $\dim(\mathcal{N}(A))$ would be $3, 2, 1, 0$. So if you have a plane of solutions for some $b$, then the image will be a line and vice-versa. Similarly, if you have a unique solution for some $b$, then the image will be the whole space. On the other hand, if $A$ takes everything to $0$, then the image is a single point.

Comment: Thank you again! I'll try and read your comments again and hopefully I'll grasp the concept soon. Sometimes it takes some days :)